# How to control the PDF output based on the compiler being used?

Tags: conditionals, compiling

I have a batch file that will compile the same input file with 3 compilers one after another as shown below. This mechanism is used to see the file size of the resulting PDF (before and after compression) generated by each compiler.

```
rem ============= LaTeX =============
latex %1
dvips %1
ps2pdf %1.ps
rename %1.pdf %1-LaTeX.pdf
copy %1-LaTeX.pdf %1-LaTeX-Compressed.pdf
compress %1-LaTeX-Compressed.pdf
cleanup %1


rem ============= PdfLaTeX =============
pdflatex %1
rename %1.pdf %1-PdfLaTeX.pdf
copy %1-PdfLaTeX.pdf %1-PdfLaTeX-Compressed.pdf
compress %1-PdfLaTeX-Compressed.pdf
cleanup %1


rem ============= XeLaTeX =============
xelatex %1
rename %1.pdf %1-XeLaTeX.pdf
copy %1-XeLaTeX.pdf %1-XeLaTeX-Compressed.pdf
compress %1-XeLaTeX-Compressed.pdf
cleanup %1
```

The problem occurs when the input file cannot be compiled with a certain compiler. If the input file, for example, contains PSTricks code then the `pdflatex` must skip the compilation and just produces a PDF output with a warning message *"Compilation has been interrupted."*.
Another example is that an input file imports PDF image that cannot be compiled with `latex`.

I need something like the followings:

### Case 1

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
  \begin{document}

    \end{document}
\fi

\iflatex
    \begin{document}

    \end{document}
\fi

\ifpdflatex
    \begin{document}

    \end{document}
\fi
```

### Case 2

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}

\iflatex
    \begin{document}

    \end{document}
\fi


\ifpdflatexorxelatex
    \begin{document}

    \end{document}
\fi
```

How to control the PDF output based on the compiler being used?

Comment: Those parts should contain the "escape" text for blocking compilation in case a wrong compiler is used?

Comment: @egreg: Yes. For example when compiling PSTricks code, the XeLaTeX and PDFLaTeX conditional block must produce a PDF output with a warning message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### First Case

A document containing PSTricks code that must be run either with `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` or `xelatex` but *not* with `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\INTERRUPT}{\shipout\hbox{Compilation interrupted}\stop}

\usepackage{etoolbox,ifpdf,ifxetex}
\ifboolexpr{ bool {pdf} } {\INTERRUPT} {}

\begin{document}

text

\end{document}
```

For only with `pdflatex`, swap the `{}` and `{\INTERRUPT}`.

### Second Case

A document that must be compiled either with `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` or `pdflatex`, but *not* with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\INTERRUPT}{\shipout\hbox{Compilation interrupted}\stop}

\usepackage{etoolbox,ifxetex}
\ifboolexpr{ bool {xetex} } {\INTERRUPT} {}

\begin{document}

text

\end{document}
```

For only with `xelatex`, swap the `{}` and `{\INTERRUPT}`.

### Third Case

A document that must be compiled either with `pdflatex` or `xelatex`, but *not* with `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\INTERRUPT}{\shipout\hbox{Compilation interrupted}\stop}

\usepackage{etoolbox,ifxetex}
\ifboolexpr{ bool {pdf} or bool {xetex} } {} {\INTERRUPT}

\begin{document}

text

\end{document}
```

For only with `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`, swap the `{}` and `{\INTERRUPT}`.

When the compiler doesn't pass the test, the low level `\shipout` operation will produce a PDF (or DVI) and `\stop` will end the run.

Comment: @DamienWalters There are more if you consider also `luatex`. :) But with the powerful boolean expression manager of `etoolbox` it's just playing with the operators `not`, `and` and `or`.

Comment: Of course. By the way, is it possible to enclose `document` environment in `\ifboolexpr`?

Comment: @DamienWalters I wouldn't use it, but it's possible; after all you want only a valid file for later processing. One might think to improve `\INTERRUPT` to show the reason for the failure. Is it worth the trouble?

Comment: What's the problem with any engine? `auto-pst-pdf` exists.